# Passing a function to an Angular validation directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have the following code, note the **name-valid** and **validation-function** tags on the `input` field.

```
<form name="createForm" novalidate>
    <div style="display: flex; width: 300px">
        <div style="flex: 3;">
            Name
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 5;">
            <input type="text" name="listName" ng-model="newListName" 
            ng-minlength="3" name-valid validation-function="someFunction"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="createForm.listName.$error.unique &&
                  !renameGoldenForm.listName.$error.minlength">already exists</div>
    <div ng-show="createForm.listName.$error.minlength">too short</div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px">
        <button ng-click="createList()" ng-disabled="createForm.listName.$invalid">
         Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the JS:

```
window.angular.module("myModule").directive("nameValid", [
    "$log",
    function($log) {
        return {
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                validationFunction: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                    var v = scope[attrs.ngModel];
                    if (!v || !((v).trim()) || v.length < 4) {
                       c.$setValidity("unique", true);
                       c.$setValidity("minlength", false);
                        return;
                    }
                    scope.validationFunction(v, scope.selectedListId)
                        .success(function(data) {
                            c.$setValidity("unique", data.unique);
                            c.$setValidity("minlength", data.minlength);
                        });
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

The problem is that having require and scope seems to break.
Is there a way to pass a custom validate function to my directive? I'm not sure how to go about it.
I've tried removing `require: 'ngModel'` and adding `ngModel` in `scope`, but that did not work either.
If I remove `scope` and hard code the function in the watch block, that works, but obviously, that defeats the purpose of having a pointer to a specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a controller function to your directive, you have to use the `&` bindings (expression binding) which allows the directive to call an expression or a function defined by a DOM attribute.

For example :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $q) {

  //Declare the func which will be bind to the directive
  $scope.func = function (data1, data2) {
    return new $q(function(resolve){
      resolve(data1 === data2);
    });
   }

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

Then we will bind this function into your directive, and we can call it into the `link` function.

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function directive() {
      return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          function: '&'
        },
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
          //Then, pass an object as argument to your function
          var promise = scope.function({data1: 5, data2: 5});

          //Retrieve result
          promise.then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
          });
        }
      };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('directive', directive);

})();
```

To finish, you can call your directive with a function attribute, in order to bind the function to your directive.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

      <directive function="func(data1, data2)"></directive>

 </body>
```